# relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC with gcc

Tags: gcc

When I compile print.s using gcc I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc45uyZj.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

1. I tried the same in another linux distribution and it worked perfectly.
2. Adding `-fPIC` doesn't help. Nor does apt-get update.
3. if you want to see the code: https://github.com/NEGU93/Compilation.git inside the Practice > Part1. Of course is the file print.s (btw. all the .s files have similar errors when I do gcc).

I guess something is missing in the Kali distro but I don't know what can it be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that your distro enables `-pie` by default (check `gcc -v` output) but your assembly is not position-independent. Try compiling a sample .c file under `-fPIC` and see how it generates calls. In your case it should be

```
call    printf@PLT
```

or you can try compiling with `gcc -no-pie`.

Comment: Solved with that! I added the "-no-pie" line and worked! Thanks a lot!
Is there a way of making it permanent though? not to have to write that line each time?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be enabled by default for all modern distros. `-no-pie` is fine, just throw it into your `CFLAGS`.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error as you when trying to link some object files compiled with clang and some with gcc. I guess these two compilers have different default settings regarding whether to produce position independent code.

So make sure you're not accidentally using the wrong compiler on part of your project.